# How can I make a counter which doesn't reset when i rerun my bot (discord.py)

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I already have a counter, but when I rerun the bot, the counter starts on 0 how can I make this better? code:

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    global counter
    counter += 1
    print(message.content)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to save the counter either simply in a text file or in a database

Text file:

```
# Gets the counter
try:
    open("counter.txt", "x").close()
    counter = 0
except:
    with open("counter.txt", "r") as file:
        counter = int(file.readlines()[0])

# Updates the counter
with open("counter.txt", "w") as file:
   file.write(str(counter))

# ...or if you're going to be updating it a lot
file = open("counter.txt", "w")
file.write(str(counter))

file.close() # Once you're completley done
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to read it from a separate file. After that you can of course read and write it.

You could use the same file as that you use for the token.